# Ionic 3 Button Resizing in height

Tags: button, ionic-framework, resize, height

I am trying to make a page with only 3 buttons in Ionic. I use:

```
<button class="botton ion-button block"> Production </button>
```

And the button resizes in width but not in height. I want it to fill all the space available.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly without knowing which display you are using, but usually to make an element fill the whole height, you would use

```
.ion-button {
    height: 100%;
}
```